# how to post data to model in loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

hello guys i m new to loopback, don't know to post data to model eg:
here is my login.ejs file

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now when user click on login how i can submit send it to model through router of directly call model root.js. i m i missing something

```
   app.post('/login', login.index);
```

how i can call login model from root.js or directly access login model js